# Evaluating $\int (\sin x)^2\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int (\sin x)^2\,dx$$

Anyone can guide me for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $(\sin x)^{2} = \dfrac{1 - \cos 2x }{2}$.  No need of substitution or by parts

Comment: can vote for me?thx!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $\quad \sin^2 x = \tfrac{1}{2}( 1 - \cos 2x)$

Comment: can vote for me?thx!